# Why can’t I link the nav bar correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to link some of the buttons to another pages but when I click it won’t take me anywhere.

```
<body>
  <li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#Our Story">Our story</a> </li>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="" id="img"> <img src="img/icons/starbucks_featured_image-1.jpg" alt="some text" height: "200" width="100"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> <a href="contact_US.html" class="nav-link">  social</a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> <a href="Social_page.html" class="nav-link">contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Where’s your opening `<ul>` tag?

Comment: you missed opening `<li> `and `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an opening `<ul>` (add `class="nav"`, if it's Bootstrap) and have an extra `</li>` in your fourth line:

```
<body>
  <ul class="nav"> <!-- please add this -->
    <li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#Our Story">Our story</a> </li>
    </li> <!-- please remove this -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="" id="img"> <img src="img/icons/starbucks_featured_image-1.jpg" alt="some text" height: "200" width="100"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a href="contact_US.html" class="nav-link">  social</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a href="Social_page.html" class="nav-link">contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: <nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="contact_US.html" class="nav-link">  social</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="Social_page.html" class="nav-link" >contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

Comment: @YossryHelal Can't see that. Okay. That looks kinda fine.